# Generic CNOT gate in qiskit from tensor product

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, qiskit

I would like to use qiskit to verify for generalized CNOT gates that, e.g. for 4 qubits
\begin{equation}
\text{cu(0,3)} = |0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes1\!\!1\otimes1\!\!1\otimes1\!\!1 + |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes1\!\!1\otimes1\!\!1\otimes\sigma_x 
\end{equation}
with control on qubit 0 and target on qubit 3, and in particular showing that the matrix representation is the same. While I know that a way to do that in a qiskit circuit is

```
test_cu = QuantumCircuit(n*2, n)

test_cu.cx(0,3)

backend_un = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
unitary = execute(test_cu, backend_un).result().get_unitary()
array_to_latex(unitary, pretext="\\text{Circuit = } ")

test_cu.draw()
```

I don't have any idea on how to make the same from basic operators and using tensor product. I've read that `Aqua` provides methods for this purpose, but I have nit found anything satisfying on the topic, neither in the official documentation (section tutorial). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [this Operator class in Aqua](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/qiskit.aqua.operators.html?highlight=operators#operators).
For example, in order to create the Operator `cu03` from your question, you can use the Pauli gates from the `operator_globals` part of Qiskit, and `^` is used as the tensor product between the gates

```
from qiskit.aqua.operators.operator_globals import Zero, One, I, X, Z
from sympy import Matrix 

op_00 = (0.5*(I+Z)) #the |0x0| state in Pauli representation
op_11 = (0.5*(I-Z)) #the |1x1| state in Pauli representation

cu_03 = (op_00^I^I^I)+(op_11^I^I^X)
Matrix(cu_03.to_matrix()) #prints nicely the matrix
```

Is this what you are looking for? If not please tell me :)

Comment: Exactly, I was searching for an example like this. Thanks a lot!